# Isolated eigenvalues of a random matrix

Tags: reference-request, random-matrices

This is a continuation of [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/458250/spectral-density-of-symmetrized-haar-matrix). Let $O$ be a random orthogonal matrix (according to Haar measure) of size $n$. I want to study the eigenvalues of the matrix $O+O^\top + \lambda uu^\top$ where $\lambda>0$ and $u$ is an arbitrary unit vector in $\mathbb R^n$. I found that as $n$ goes to infinity, the spectrum consists of eigenvalues with limiting density given by the arcsin law rescaled to the interval $[-2,2]$ and an isolated eigenvalue on the right. Let $\lambda_{max}$ and $u_{max}$ be the maximum eigenvalue and the corresponding unit eigenvector. Then
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \lambda_{max} = \sqrt{\lambda^2+4},
$$
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (u_{max}^\top u)^2 = \frac{\lambda}{\sqrt{\lambda^2+4}}.
$$
I obtained these results by the non-rigorous replica method and verified them by simulations.

So my question is whether a rigorous proof of these results can be found in the literature (I can't find it in the reference given in the answer of the mentioned mathoverflow question). If you have a simple proof I would be eager to know.

Comment: What does the sentence « I found that the spectrum consists of eigenvalues that form a continuous density » mean? What is « the » eigenvector $u_\max$ mean? The square norm $u_\max^\top u_\max$ can be any fixed positive number).

Comment: for your second equation I find  $ (u_{\text{max}}^\top u)^2 = \frac{\lambda}{\sqrt{\lambda^2+4}}$, so with a square on the left-hand-side.

Comment: That's right. I actually meant that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use results from [Forrester's article](https://arxiv.org/abs/2201.00324) (written for a rank-one perturbation of a matrix from the GOE, but more generally valid for an isotropic random-matrix ensemble).

**A. Largest eigenvalue**

Equation (2.6) in that paper gives the largest eigenvalue $\lambda_{\text max}$ of $O+O^\top+\lambda uu^\top$, with $n\gg 1$, as the solution of
$$1-\lambda\int \frac{P(\mu)}{\lambda_{\text{max}}-\mu}\,d\mu=0,$$
with
$$P(\mu)=\frac{1}{\pi\sqrt{4-\mu^2}},\;\;|\mu|<2,$$
the large-$n$ eigenvalue density of $O+O^\top$ calculated in my previous [answer.](https://mathoverflow.net/a/458259/11260)
This gives the equation
$$\frac{2}{\pi  \sqrt{\lambda_{\text{max}}^2-4}} \left[\arctan\left(\frac{\lambda_{\text{max}}-2}{\sqrt{\lambda_{\text{max}}^2-4}}\right)+\arctan\left(\frac{\lambda_{\text{max}}+2}{\sqrt{\lambda_{\text{max}}^2-4}}\right)\right]=\frac{1}{\lambda},$$
with solution
$$\lambda_{\text{max}}=\sqrt{\lambda^2+4}.$$

**B. Eigenvector of largest eigenvalue**

From page 20 of Forrester I find, again for $n\gg 1$,
$$(u_{\text{max}}^\top u)^2=\left(\int \frac{P(\mu)}{(\lambda_{\rm max}-\mu)^2}\,d\mu\right)^{-1}\left(\int \frac{P(\mu)}{\lambda_{\rm max}-\mu}\,d\mu\right)^2$$
$$\qquad = \frac{\lambda}{\sqrt{\lambda^2+4}}.$$